# Extracting object attributes from pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, object, dataframe

I am using the Python FinTS library to get my account statements from the bank in MT940 format and to further process it with `pandas`. The amount column however is not a float but an MT940 library amount object, which has the actual amount and the currency inside (see http://mt940.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mt940.html).

```
0       <-7.99 EUR>
1      <-22.12 EUR>
2      <-66.19 EUR>
3      <-11.49 EUR>
```

How can I access the amount component of these objects? My working but totally unpythonic approach was to cast them to `str` and to slice the amount out before casting it to float again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `map` + `operator.attrgetter`

Call `map` with an `operator.attrgetter` callable. This is short and concise.

```
from operator import attrgetter
df['amount'] = df['column'].map(attrgetter('amount'))
```

---

#### List comprehension

This is another powerful alternative, and fast.

```
df['amount'] = [x.amount for x in df['column'].tolist()]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.I'll accept this answer in 10 minutes

Comment: It's been 60minutes (-: